# Hiperligações em tabelas php

Tags: php

Estou a fazer um site para um clube de futsal e criei uma tabela com os nomes dos jogadores em php que vai buscar informações a uma base de dados e queria, se possível, fazer hiperligações através dos nomes para páginas com informações mais detalhadas sobre os jogadores.
Este é código para criar as tabelas:

```
<?php 
$servername ="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="casaldogrilo";
//cria conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// verifica conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM juniores order by Nome ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table style='width:100%' height='100%'>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Data_Nasc</th>
    <th>Idade</th>
    <th>Nacionalidade</th>
    </tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td align='center'>".$row["Nome"]."</td>
    <td align='center'>".$row["Data_Nasc"]."</td>
    <td align='center'>".$row["Idade"]."</td>
    <td align='center'>".$row["Nacionalidade"]."</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

[image: Esta é a tabela onde quero fazer as hiperligações]

Comment: O jogadores têm um id na tabela da BD?

Comment: Na tabela da BD os jogadores apenas tem nome, data nascimento e nacionalidade

Comment: O que torna um jogador unico na tabela? Pelo menos deveria incluir um campo `id` em auto-increment na tabela, para que cada jogador tenha um id unico. Porque assim se dois jogadores tiverem o mesmo nome/data nascimento/nacionalidade, qual deles é que quer?

Comment: Depois de incluir o campo id, como deverá ficar o código php?

Comment: Estou a responder a isso. É um pouco grande a resposta. Faça isso e depois venha que já deve estar. Deixe em auto-increment a coluna id

Comment: E já agora pode incluir o codigo da sua conecção (sem passwords) só para ver como está a estruturar isso

Comment: Amigo @MiguelSousa coloque os códigos apenas na sua pergunta, deixar código nos comentários pode confundir alguém  , o Miguel estar a responder então sugiro que aguarde as sugestões e depois fazer perguntas, pode ser que a resposta realmente demore um pouco , mas aguarde um pouco.

Comment: Respondi em baixo, espero que se adeque

Comment: (Peço desculpa se estiver a ser ignorante) Já coloquei os códigos acima mas depois aparece-me o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\Pap\juvenis.php on line 75. Estou a fazer alguma coisa mal? @Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aproveitando o código que tem, que creio que funciona, vamos acrescentar anchors (href):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table style='width:100%' height='100%'>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Data_Nasc</th>
<th>Idade</th>
<th>Nacionalidade</th>
</tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="jogador.php?id=' .$row["id"]. '">' .$row["Nome"]. '</a></td>
        <td align="center">' .$row["Data_Nasc"]. '</td>
        <td align="center">' .$row["Idade"]. '</td>
        <td align="center">' .$row["Nacionalidade"]. '</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Depois na página jogador.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    die('Não existe um id definido');
}
if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die('ID inválido');
}
else {
    $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "casaldogrilo"; // cria conexão
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // verifica conexão
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM juniores WHERE id=" .$_GET['id'];
    if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        die ('problema na query');
    }
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $jogador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo 'Nome: ' .$jogador['Nome']. '<br>';
        echo 'Data Nascimento: ' .$jogador['Data_Nasc']. '<br>';
        echo 'Idade: ' .$jogador['Idade']. '<br>';
        echo 'Nacionalidade: ' .$jogador['Nacionalidade']. '<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Jogador não encontrado';
    }
}
```

Note que vamos fazer [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) ao parametro id que está no URL, que pertence ao jogador onde clicou para ver os detalhes. Por ex: jogador.php?id=1 , neste caso vamos buscar os detalhes à BD (na página jogador.php) o jogador cujo o id é 1. Note também que onde existe `die()` pode colocar o que quiser, é só para lhe mostrar os erros que podem ocorrer visto que isto são inputs do utilizador nunca confiar a 100%. Mas em princípio isto funciona perfeitamente assim.

Comment: Por favor, não usem os comentários para longas discussões. Movi todos para o [chat aqui](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41378/discussion-on-answer-by-miguel-hiperligacoes-em-tabelas-php). Da próxima vez, por favor, criem uma sala de chat se precisarem se prolongar em algum assunto. Abraço!